# Common.Logging for custom built log4net

Tags: log4net, log4net-configuration

How can i configure the Common.Logging->log4net which log4net built with a different .snk file?
when i want to build the Project it looks for log4net that has a PublicKeyToken=1b44e1d426115821, but mine is different. I tried to identify my log4net assembly as below. that doesn't work.

```
<configSections>
<sectionGroup name="common">
  <section name="logging" type="Common.Logging.ConfigurationSectionHandler, Common.Logging" />
</sectionGroup>
<section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net,Version=1.2.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=XXXXXXXXXXXX"/>
```

thanks

Comment: I updated my answer with one more option for you. I'm not sure if it is something you would consider, but I thought I would mention it anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you made Common.Logging reference your version of log4net and then rebuilt it (Common.Logging)?

I suspect that you will have to open the Common.Logging.Log4Net project and change the reference to log4net from the log4net that Common.Logging redistributes to your log4net.  I think that you should then be able to rebuild Common.Logging and you should also be able to reference your version of log4net in the configuration.

UPDATE...
Another idea would be to write your own log4net factory adapter. Just use the exact source code from Commom.Logging's log4net factory adapter project. There is not really much code there. In your project, reference your own log4net. Configure Common.Logging to use your factory adapter. I don't know that this option is any more or less attractive than rebuilding Commom.Logging with your version of log4net, but I thought I would mention it anyway.

Comment: Possibly it would work. But i dont want to Rebuild the Common.Logging source to search for my custom Log4net.dll. I guess there should be another way to implement my own Log4net. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is using an assembly version redirect as described here:  http://netcommon.sourceforge.net/docs/2.0.0/reference/html/ch01.html#d4e47 but I think that only works for redirecting to another version of the same assembly (that has been signed with the same key)  Do you have to have your own version of log4net?  Maybe there is another way to accomplish whatever you are trying to do?